# How to create TCHAR array, that contains Upper Case letters from A to Z?

Tags: c++, tchar

How to create TCHAR array, that contains Upper Case letters from A to Z?

Any code samples are welcome!

Thank you!

Comment: TCHAR myArray[] = _T("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");

Comment: How to fill array programmatically? Not like _T("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"); , because I need it for many languages and I don't want to hardcode all alphabets of all languages.